# Show the convergence rate is at least quadratic

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

> Suppose $p$ is a simple root of $f(x)=0$ and $f^{(5)}(x)$ is continuous in the neighborhood of $p$. Define
>   $$g(x)=x-{f(x) \over f'(x)}-{f''(x)\over {2f'(x)}}\left({f(x)\over f'(x)}\right)^2.$$ Show that the convergence rate of the fixed point iteration $p_n=g(p_{n-1})$ is at least cubic if $p_n\to p$.

The theorem says that if $g'(p)=g''(p)=g'''(p)=\dotsb=g^{(m-1)}(p), g^{(m)}(p) \neq 0$ for some $m \geq 2$ and $g^{(m)}(x)$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $p$, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{{p-p_n}\over{(p-p_{n-1})^m}}\right|={|g^{(m)}(p)|\over m!}>0$$
and the rate of convergence is $m$. I am getting some nasty derivative and expressions. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

I proved that the first two derivatives of $g(x)$ at p are zero. However, I have the problem with the last derivative which has to be non zero. I got
$$g'''(p)=3({f''(p)\over f'(p)})^2-{f'''(p)\over f'(p)}\neq 0$$ How I show that it is indeed not equal to zero?

Comment: In principle you can just do the derivatives, but especially the second one will be a pain to do. The easier thing to do is to write $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ in finite Taylor expansions at $x=r$, leaving $o((x-r)^3)$ error terms. In particular, where $f^{(5)}$ comes into play is in $f''(x)=f''(r)+f^{(3)}(r)(x-r)+1/2 f^{(4)}(r)(x-r)^2+1/6 f^{(5)}(r)(x-r)^3+o((x-r)^3)$.

Comment: "Maybe I am doing something wrong." Well what did you do? Did you try writing out the first few derivatives of $p$? Show us what you've done.

Comment: The actual derivative is a huge expression. I edited and gave it when p is plugged in.

Comment: Why do you need the last one to be non-zero? Having it zero will only improve the convergence!

Comment: Because that is what the theorem tells me. It has to converge for this theorem to be valid.

Comment: The theorem you use tells you when the convergence rate is *exactly* cubic. You are to show that it's at least cubic (so it can be quartic, quintic, ...). If $g'''(p) = 0$ then the convergence rate will be better than cubic.

Comment: So if it is at least cubic it doesn't have to be higher order. It wants me to show that it is not linear or quadratic.

Comment: Yeah, to show it is at least cubic you only need to show that $g'(p)=g''(p)=0$. If $f$ is "just right" then it could converge even faster.

Comment: But it can be right and if you insist on applying the theorem as written then you don't cover these cases. Instead try to think about what it really means for the convergence rate if that limit happens to be zero. What does that tell you about the rate that $p_n$ approaches $p$? Is it faster/slower than cubic?